# Error in Returning a Class Object in C++

Tags: c++, function, class, object, return

I've been working on a Matrix library for personal use lately. I've tried writing code that returns my Matrix class (such as operator overloads, transformations, and inversions), but a strange error occurs. Visual Studio says that it throws a break point, possibly due to a corrupted heap, and then it says something about a debug error. I've tried several members of my code, and only the code that returns a Matrix fails in this manner.

I was thinking about passing a preallocated object's pointer through the member's arguments, but that just doesn't work with the operator overloads apparently. Any help?

Here are the error messages:

> Windows has triggered a breakpoint in Project Sapphire.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   Project Sapphire.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while Project
>   Sapphire.exe has focus."
>
> "Debug Assertion Failed!
>
> Program: ...\Desktop\Programs\Project Sapphire\Debug\Project
>   Sapphire.exe file: minkernal\crts\ucrt\src\appcrt\heap\debug_heap.cpp
>   line 888
>
> Expression: _CrtlsValidHeapPointer(block)
>
> For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure,
>   see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts
>
> (Press Retry to debug the application)

Here's the code:

**Matrix.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <vector>

class Matrix
{
private:
std::vector<std::vector<float>> data;

public:
std::vector<int> getSize();

//Operator overloads
std::vector<float> operator[](int index);
Matrix operator+(const Matrix& fuz);

//Constructor and destructor
Matrix(int dim1, int dim2);
~Matrix();
};
```

**Matrix.cpp**

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
#include "Matrix.h"

std::vector<int> Matrix::getSize() //This seems to work well
{
    std::vector<int> size(2);
    size[0] = data.size();
    size[1] = (data.size() >= 1 ) ? data[0].size() : 0; //Makes sure to not try to access an empty vector
    return size;
}

//Operator Overloads
std::vector<float> Matrix::operator[](int index)
{
    return data.at(index); //Does the same thing as data[], from what I can tell
}

Matrix Matrix::operator+(const Matrix& fuz)
{
    if (( fuz.data.size() == this->getSize()[0]) && (fuz.data[0].size() == this->getSize()[1])) //Makes sure that the matrix dimensions align
    {
        Matrix ret = *this; //The return matrix. Starts out as a copy of this matrix
        for (int i = 0; i < this->getSize()[0]; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < (int) this->getSize()[1]; j++)
            {
                ret[i][j] += fuz.data[i][j]; //Goes through and adds the two matrices
            }
        }
        return ret; //Error happens HERE
    }
    return Matrix(1, 1); //Otherwise, return a scalar
}

//Constructor and Destructor
Matrix::Matrix(int dim1, int dim2)
{
    data.resize(dim1); //Allocate the first dimension of the matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < dim1; i++) //Allocate the second dimension of the matrix
        data[i].resize(dim2);
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this->getSize()[0] - 1; i++) //Destruct each vector inside of the vector
        data[i].~vector();
    data.~vector(); //Delete the actual data
    delete[] & data; //Finally, delete data
}
```

**ProjectSapphire.cpp**

```
    // Project Sapphire.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"

#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

//#include "Node.h"
#include "Matrix.h"

//namespace SWF = System::Windows::Forms;


int main()
{

    Matrix test(2,3);

    int size[] = { test.getSize()[0], test.getSize()[1] };

    test[0][0] = 1;
    test[0][1] = 2;
    test[0][2] = 3;
    test[1][0] = 4;
    test[1][1] = 5;
    test[1][2] = 6;

    Matrix foo = test;

    Matrix deet = foo + test;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you cannot return ret, then presumably there is no copy constructor on Matrix.

Comment: You probably have many bugs in the code you're not showing, as well as bugs in what you have shown. You should post an MCVE.

Comment: can you copy/paste ther exact error please ? It will allow us to help you better, and allow people having the exact same problem to find the answer easily

Comment: this looks a bit sketchy: `fuz.data.size() == this->getSize()[0]) && (fuz.data[0].size()== this->getSize()[1]` how is "data" declared?

Comment: @AndersK. data is declared as an std::vector< std::vector< float > >. I was changing things around a bit. The old code didn't have fuz.data.size but fuz.getSize()[0]. That stopped working when I tried using const Matrix& instead of just Matrix&.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but I'd suggest that `getSize()` returns `std::pair`. This has less overhead and is easier to use than a 2-element vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code in your destructor is utter nonsense. It is probably the source of your problem.

Remove all of the code in the destructor (preferably, remove the destructor entirely).

At a quick glance, your code looks OK apart from that.

It causes undefined behaviour to invoke the destructor twice for a vector. (The destructor of member variables is invoked by the compiler after the class's destructor, if any, finishes).

Answer (score 0):

Just never call destructor manually. Read about [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization). All objects are destructed automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe Matrix's copy/move constructor is broken/deleted/private.